# Is it possible to set the same tax rate to all the countries.Instead of setting the tax rate for each country

Tags: magento2, tax

I want set the equal tax rate for all the countries.For example i am in global store, in checkout if i select any country same tax should be applied.(if we set the tax rates for each countries separately is it possible but instead of setting for each country is it possible.)

Comment: Put `*` marks in `country` and `state` fields.

Comment: How do you put a * mark in country when create new tax rate in admin? The country field is a dropdown list that you can only choose value from.